# Looking for real world example for ServiceStack

Tags: unit-testing, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

As someone who wasted weeks this Autumn to configure and reconfigure IIS servers for WCF, authentication, making EntityFramework behave etc, I really want to use ServiceStack in the new upcoming project.

I want to go all-in, i.e. I would like to completely skip Microsoft specific stuff this time.

I am looking for a real-world example using ServiceStack, I have been looking at Rockstars and SocialBootstrapApi, but I want something bigger.

My requirements:

- It should be at least be two subprojects, one containing the web part, and one the business logic.
- I do not expect any ServiceStack stuff except ServiceStack.OrmLite and some common things in the business logic part
- Unit tests for business logic
- Unit tests for ServiceStack services

Do anyone know about such a project where I can look at the source?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for a prescribed n-tier architecture with an expectation of how it should be built. The fact you're using [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/) is a red-herring here, as a ServiceStack service is just a standard, auto-wired C# class that's completely mockable and testable in isolation (so you you would test it as you would any other class) or test it as an [Integration Test](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/RazorRockstars.Console.Files/ReqStarsService.cs) using a self-hosted ServiceStack HttpListener.

I personally dislike prescribed architectures as I prefer to re-factor my code-base as it grows and only add architecture and delegation as needed. I provide examples of how I separate layers in my ServiceStack services and describe some of the [different levels of architecture I commonly have within the same application in this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/servicestack/1pA41E33QII/R-trWwzYgjEJ). The one thing that ServiceStack tries to encourage is to keep your Service Models in a separate and largely dep-free assembly that's de-coupled from your implementation.

OrmLite doesn't require any special attention compared to any other DAL either. If you choose to encapsulate it inside a Repository class then you're left with a standard C# class (i.e. the Repository) that just accepts and returns clean POCOs. Depending on your preferred method of testing your data access layer, you can choose to mock the repository when testing your services or choose to use an in-memory Sqlite db and mock the RDBMS database with test data for integration tests that also tests RDBMS access.

Basically ServiceStack embeds an IOC and promotes clean Dependency-injected C# services allowing you the freedom to test your services in the preferred style you're already accustomed to. i.e. you shouldn't need to change your architecture or testing strategies to support ServiceStack as it should already give you the freedom to develop services as you normally would.

Comment: Thanks @mythz, good design information. You should collect all your links about design somewhere on the site, incl your two latest interviews.

Comment: However, the reason I was looking for a sample was more to get tips on micro-level. I know system design, so most of my programming time is not devoted on questions like "How in the hell should I do this thing with this tool?".  I have a follow-up questions: Is it even possible to make a self-hosted project of a ServiceStack+MVC3?

Comment: not => now::::::

However, the reason I was looking for a sample was more to get tips on micro-level. I know system design, so most of my programming time is **NOW** devoted on questions like "How in the hell should I do this thing with this tool?" and then sample code is best.